# how to update a column from one Table to another based on a ID match

Tags: sql, join, sql-update

I have two table with column name department . when i  update the department column in table1 at the same time it has to be updated column in table 2 based on id.
Now I need to update those records where the ID matches with the department.

```
update t1
set t1.dept=t2.dept
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
on t1.id=t2.id
```

Comment: What is your question, and/or what is wrong with the update query you currently have?

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected output.

Comment: what dbms are u using

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and using a JOIN in an UPDATE statement is not possible in standard SQL. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Fix your data model so the department name is stored in only one place (a table with a name like `departments`).  Don't store a single value in multiple tables.  Use `join` to lookup the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Note: I just used MySQL-syntax here, as you didn't specify. You need to adapt to your own dbms if you dont use MySQL.***

There are two ways in which this can be accomplished.

**Using a sub-query:**

Using a sub-query is relatively straight forward:

```
update table2
set table2.dept = (
    select table1.dept 
    from table1
    where table1.id = table2.id
    limit 1
)
-- We need this, because if we don't have 
-- it then table2.dept will be null whenever 
-- there is no entry in table1 with the same id
where 0 < (select count(*) from table2 where table2.id = table1.id)
;
```

This is mostly handy if you only want to do this occasionally, but i can't really see why you would want to.

This is also not that efficient to do, if you have a big table.

**Using a trigger:**

I think using a trigger is nicer, as you just set it up and then it'll work its magic in the background:

```
delimiter //
create trigger updateDepartment
after update 
on table1 for each row
begin 
  -- new refers to the new row (with updated values)
  update table2 
  set dept = new.dept
  where id = new.id;
end; //

delimiter ;
```

You can read more about [MySQL triggers here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html). There are more types of triggers, such as triggers which trigger when there is an insert, or a delete.